# How to Migrate WSS 3.0 workflows to SharePoint 2010?

Tags: wss-3.0, migration

I need to migrate WSS 3.0 workflows to my new SharePoint 2010 site.

There are many list with many workflows...

Can someone list easiest method of migration?

Thanks!

-saumil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of workflows are we talking about?

SharePoint-OOTB Workflows?
SharePoint Designer?
Nintex/K2?
Visual Studio?

How have they been deployed?
Manual?
Scripted?
WSP installation?

Comment: SharePoint Designer > Some Manual & Some WSP Installation ... Thx

Comment: Hi Alex, I have manually created workflows and I need to migrate it to SP 2010 with all associations etc intact. Is this possible? Thx

Comment: Hi Saumil, I think it really depends on your workflows. You can identify some issues with the PreUpdateCheck tool. After that I would try to re-deploy the WSP workflows to the new environment and then do a test migration via content database attach. I guess the more complex your workflows are the more trouble you will get to migrate them. Lots of people ended up recreating their SPD workflows. Another way would be to pay for 3rd party tool but I dont know if thats an option for you